# How to rename nested directories and files recursively using pysmb in python?

Tags: python, recursion, samba, pysmb

Recently, I had to rename all space characters used in the directory and file names in a Samba tree.
Before that, I used `os.walk` to traverse the directory tree of regular files in python, but I wanted to rename them in-place.

To connect to my Samba server and rename a single file, I used this snippet:

```
from smb import SMBConnection

conn = SMBConnection.SMBConnection(userID, password, client_machine_name, server_name, is_direct_tcp=True, domain='workgroup')
assert conn.connect('1.2.3.4')

shares = conn.listShares()
    for share in shares:
        if share.name == 'share':
            conn.rename('share', 'path/old_name', 'path/new_name')
```

My problem is when I rename parent directories to new names, I can't access their children anymore. How can I rename old directories and files recursively using `pysmb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find a sample code as follow in pysmb [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33338244/15144104) as `os.walk`:

```
def smb_walk(conn, shareddevice, top='/'):
    dirs, nondirs = [], []
    if not isinstance(conn, SMBConnection.SMBConnection):
        raise TypeError("SMBConnection required")
    names = conn.listPath(shareddevice, top)
    for name in names:
        if name.isDirectory:
            if name.filename not in [u'.', u'..']:
                dirs.append(name.filename)
        else:
            nondirs.append(name.filename)
    yield top, dirs, nondirs
    for name in dirs:
        new_path = os.path.join(top, name)
        for x in smb_walk(conn, shareddevice, new_path):
            yield x
```

Then I rename directories and files recursively from the innermost directory (because the files path name before them name renaming sholdn't changed):

```
ans = smb_walk(conn, 'share', top=source_path)
smb_l = list(ans)
for s_i in smb_l[::-1]:
    for s_j in s_i[2][::-1]:
        if s_j:
            #rename file name
            conn.rename('share', f'{s_i[0]}/{s_j}', f'{s_i[0]}/{encode_n(s_j)}')
    for s_j in s_i[1][::-1]:
        if s_j:
            #rename directory name
            conn.rename('share', f'{s_i[0]}/{s_j}', f'{s_i[0]}/{encode_n(s_j)}')
```